# Instagram feed image not displaying

Tags: php, html, image, feed, instagram

I am successfully pulling in the `url` for each image for a particular `tag` via PHP, but the image simply will not display.  I saved the image(s) off locally and it displayed just fine, but not when referencing the `url` in the `src` attribute.

```
<img src="http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/1597216_736275239737299_176271816_a.jpg" />
```

You can follow the above source link to the image, and this is how the `img` tag is set in html, but it will not display in the browser.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can this have something to do with REFERER-check?

I mean - my chrome doesn't shows up WHY the request get's blocked, when I embed it to a website.

You should figure it out (my linux-curl shows the pic with referer set, but i'm not sure if this works!).
An idea would be to provide a php-file which is just a WRAPPER for sending to image:

```
<?php // redirect.php
header('Location: ' . $_GET('r'));
die();
```

usage:

```
<img src="redirect.php?r=<?php echo urlencode('http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/1597216_736275239737299_176271816_a.jpg"');" />
```

Because modern browsern do not send "REFERER" when redirected through status-header `302 Redirect`

just have a try...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just tried this with no luck.  I did notice that it is only in Chrome (Mac) that this issue is occurring.  I've tested in all other browsers (on Windows as well) and the feed displays fine.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry - no... Indeed it can be a chrome-bug!

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related--Facebook share dialogs that attempt to share images from the FB CDN origincache end up with a 500 Internal Server Error and a blank page. I know that FB throws an error when sharing other images on FB, but you usually get a descriptive error message and not just a server error.